# Force a package to not upgrade

Tags: 12.04, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

How can I force a package to stay at the current version, even though there's an update?

Answer (score 2):

That is a fairly simple setting you can set from ***Synaptic Package Manager.***

Select the package you do not want to upgrade, then head over to the menubar and click *Package->Lock Version*

This will force the selected package not to upgrade.

[image]